# Getting Complex Result With Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the two tables `Issue` and `Received`. I want to get result with same row of issue.

Issue table:

| NO | LCODE | PCS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L0001 | 10 |
| 2 | L0002 | 25 |
| 3 | L0003 | 75 |
| 4 | L0004 | 12 |
| 5 | L0005 | 15 |

Received table:

| NO | LCODE | PCS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L0001 | 5 |
| 2 | L0001 | 5 |
| 3 | L0003 | 48 |
| 4 | L0003 | 12 |
| 5 | L0003 | 15 |

Wanted result:

| NO | LCODE | ISSPCS | RECPCS | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L0001 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | L0001 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | L0003 | 75 | 48 | 27 |
| 4 | L0003 | 0 | 12 | 15 |
| 5 | L0003 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| 6 | L0004 | 12 | 0 | 12 |
| 7 | L0005 | 15 | 0 | 15 |

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.LCODE ORDER BY i.LCODE) as NO,
i.LCODE,i.PCS as ISSPCS,r.PCS as RECPCS,(i.PCS-r.PCS) as BAL 
FROM Issue i
LEFT JOIN Received  r ON i.LCODE = r.LCODE
```

Find The Best Way To Getting This Result Thank you.

Comment: if you could explain how the result meant and how to be achieved in layman terms it would be helpful. for instance the `BAL` thing, i see it as the difference between "Issue PCS" and "received PCS". However, it comes blank to me how on earth that one on 4th row got like 15 while having isspcs 0 and 12 recpcs. we cant help you unless you help us understand the problem first. also, a mandatory PSA, please post what you have tried so far - stackoverflow is a discussion platform not a code generator.

Comment: @BagusTesa it is 75 issue and received 48 show now balance is 27 after second received 12 show my balance was 27 -12 = 15 after it received 15 it 0.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have write my query here I can't getting result that I wanted.

Comment: hi piyush, its not the table that being unclear. its the last step you mentioned in the comment that was missing from the original question. given it works that way, i dont think a simple join can solve stuff. gotta need some while-loop thing in mysql to solve it.

Comment: @BagusTesa it's some problem in formatting that's why happened. please help me to getting this result, I was try in many way but not getting this stuff.

Comment: You will need a case expression for your isspcs column in the resultset to "replace" the value from issued when there are multiple rows for a given LCODE. Given that you have no set of columns that can be used for consistent ordering, the row_number value is not deterministic but that's a different problem. And if order matters - which is usually does - your query must have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: You could also search on "running balance" to similar discussions. The inability to order in a deterministic fashion will be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY i.LCODE ASC, RunninngSum ASC) AS [NO]
,       i.LCODE
,       CASE WHEN RunninngSum > r.PCS THEN 0 ELSE i.PCS 
        END AS ISSPCS
,       ISNULL( r.PCS, 0) AS RECPCS
,       i.PCS - ISNULL( RunninngSum, 0) as BAL
FROM Issue i
LEFT JOIN Received r ON i.LCODE = r.LCODE 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM( r1.PCS) AS RunninngSum 
    FROM Received r1 
    WHERE r1.LCODE = r.LCODE AND r1.[NO] <= r.[NO]
)x
```